# How can I easily save the HTML pages of my Rails app, to give to Designer?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I am working on a Rails app, and a designer is designing the raw HTML pages separately.  Its tough to get his environment set up to use the application directly, so I would like to be able to somehow "store" the HTML of all of the pages that my application generates, to a  directory somewhere to that I can pass the curent version off to the designer.

Does anyone know of a gem or rake task that would help me do something likee this?

I am also open to other suggestions for working in parallel with designers who don't know rails.

Thanks

**Edit**

I guess an amendment to my question, would be, does anyone also know of ways of generating the list of page links to feed to wget, other than going through them by hand

**Edit 2**

Just thinking out loud...   to generate every possible page in an app, you'd need to call every action in every controller.  So i'd need a program to find which controllers exist in all of my app/gems/plugins, and then find all of the public methods in them..    Or..  maybe I could just use the actions that are routable from the list of routes

Then, you might want to filter out the actions that didn't render html

Then you might want to filter out destructive actions (unless this program ran in a test environment, and rebuilt the system every time).

Then as many actions depend on the parameters that are supplied, you'd need to have control over which parameters are sent to each action...

Then you'd also have to be able to send session cookies to log in

what else..

Comment: @ your edits: Something like that will probably need to be custom. I don't think it'd be too difficult, though - launch your app in a test environment, create + save a few models, then visit [every route of the application](http://snipplr.com/view/2415/), providing those model IDs. (with a CRUD app you'd visit "create" first, then "read," then "update," and "destroy")

Answer (score 5):

```
wget -m http://somewhere.com
```

This command will fetch all the files / pages from http://somewhere.com and download them to a local directory, to form a local "mirror."

> ```
>    -m
>    --mirror
>        Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns
>        on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and
>        keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l
>        inf --no-remove-listing.
> ```

Note: I don't believe Mac OS X ships with `wget`. If you are using a Mac, I'd suggest installing [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then running `brew install wget`.

Read more: [`man wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)